# SQL query next lowest value

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have the following table:

```
_id price   gallons odometer
1   3.19    15  10000
2   3.25    13.2    10200
3   3.24    14.8    10400
4   3.31    15.3    10600
5   3.31    12.8    11000
6   3.29    12.9    10800
7   3.32    14.3    10900
8   3.28    15.1    11200
9   3.27    11.7    11400
10  3.21    14.7    11600
```

I need to calculate fuel mileage by using the current odometer reading, with the previous, and the amount of gallons.  My problem is, if the odometer readings are not entered in order (or if a user goes back to change the value of one, how do I calculate the new MPG?)

Example:

```
_id price   gallons odometer
1   3.19    10  10000 <-- First entry has no MPG rating since there is no previous data
2   3.25    10  10200 <-- 20 MPG based off the difference of row 2 & 1 and 10 gallons
3   3.24    10  10400 <-- 20 MPG based off the difference of row 3 & 2 and 10 gallons
4   3.31    10  10600 <-- 20 MPG based off the difference of row 4 & 3 and 10 gallons
5   3.31    10  11000 <-- This row will initially show 40MPG difference of row 5 & 4 (since row 6 isnt in yet)
6   3.29    10  10800 <-- once this is entered, it goes to 20MPG difference of 6 & 4 (4 is next lowest odometer reading after 6) and then 10 becomes 20MPG difference from 5 & 6
```

I think you can see where I am going with this.  from the odometer column, when i calculate the MPG, i need to always grab the next lowest odometer reading which should be from the most previous entry.  In some cases, if a user goes back and edits one, or maybe skips one and adds it at a later date, it would need to adjust for that.

This is all going into an android app, but I am mainly curious of how the SQL would be written.  I may need to do some sort of If statement and run through all the values or something?  Looking for anyones input.

If you need further clarification, please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Just to confirm, the ID column will not always be in ascending order with the odometer? Row 9 might have an odometer reading that is lower than row 8, for instance, depending on when the data is entered?

Comment: For instance someone may forget to put in an entry and then log it at a later date after they realize they forgot it.  Thats when it could be out of order

Comment: I gave you a query that will give you current/prior values, but in your example above, you have 10 gallons being used on each row, the difference between the current/prior values on those rows are not actually 10, is that because you just wanted to simplify it?

Comment: Yes i was just simplifying it. Essentially i am trying to take the difference from current odometer taking to previous so say 200 miles, divide that by 10 gallons to fill the tank which tells you your 200 miles were at 20mpg

Comment: Is 10 gallons the # of gallons on the current row? (not the difference between the gallons on the current and prior row)

Comment: I think I get it, if 10 is the current row's gallons value, the query in my last edit should work.

Comment: Ok cool. Yeah the difference in gallons will never be calculated since that's irrelevant in determining mpg

Comment: I am going to try this tomorrow when i have a bit more time, then will accept your answer. Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: No problem, if you run into any issues let me know and I'll take a look (at night probably)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you the ingredients for what you need. I didn't understand your MPG calculation but this has the current and previous odometer and gallons values onto the same row, which should allow you to do what you need to do.

```
select x.*,
       y.odometer as prev_odom,
       y.gallons as prev_gallons,
       (x.odometer - y.odometer) / x.gallons as mpg
  from tbl x, tbl y
 where y.odometer =
       (select max(z.odometer) from tbl z where z.odometer < x.odometer)
union
select x.*, null, null, null
from tbl x
where id = 1
order by 1
```

**SQL Fiddle demo:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/394d7/36/0

EDITED - Had to change previous odometer to show 0 on ID 2 via case statement.
EDITED again - Incoporated MPG calculation

Answer (score 0):

Since it's an app, you don't have to do everything in one step.  I don't know android programming, so I'll show you the logic with generic code.

```
currentOdometerReading = 11000;
```

run this query,  passing the above variable as a paramter

```
 select gallons, 
 (select max(odometer) 
 from yourTable
 where odometer < @paramterFromYourApp) prevOdometerReading
 where odometer = @paramterFromYourApp
```

back to your app

```
milesPerGallon = (currentOdometerReading - thePrevOdometerReadingValue from your query) 
  / theGallonsValueFromYourQuery;
```

Just bear in mind that if a record has not been entered yet, this won't give the correct answer.  But then again, neither will anything else.  That would be a process where you don't look for very recent data.